# Illustrator created svg graphic not displaying/scaling properly in html

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created this Instagram icon in Illustrator. I am trying to get it to display properly on an HTML page but it's not working properly. After exporting the svg image I copy the svg code generated by Illustrator into my HTML and it scales funny; cutting out some edges and making the strokes much thicker. It appears to be independent of parent element.

Scaling the svg using its height and width property or transform doesn't do anything and the viewBox dimensions match that of the image. Check out the screenshots.
[image]

Generated svg code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 22 22">
    <g id="Shape">
      <path class="cls-1" d="M16,22.2H6.41A6.21,6.21,0,0,1,.2,16V6.41A6.22,6.22,0,0,1,6.41.2H16a6.21,6.21,0,0,1,6.2,6.21V16A6.21,6.21,0,0,1,16,22.2ZM6.41,2.2A4.22,4.22,0,0,0,2.2,6.41V16a4.21,4.21,0,0,0,4.21,4.2H16A4.2,4.2,0,0,0,20.2,16V6.41A4.21,4.21,0,0,0,16,2.2Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="M11.2,17A5.78,5.78,0,1,1,17,11.2,5.79,5.79,0,0,1,11.2,17Zm0-9.56A3.78,3.78,0,1,0,15,11.2,3.79,3.79,0,0,0,11.2,7.42Z"/>
      <circle class="cls-1" cx="17" cy="5.14" r="1.25"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

How it looks in the browser:
[image]

Comment: Not sure how you went about creating or exporting the shapes but they are definitely bigger than the bounds of your artboard, your very first M command goes to 22.4 whereas your viewBox is only 22 wide. The clipped corners are being done by you somewhere in your CSS, check through the inspector. As far as the shapes being bigger than in Illustrator, probably also CSS adding a stroke to the shapes.

Comment: If I just put your SVG into an empty HTML page, with no CSS, it displays to the edges as expected. You obviously have some CSS to make the lines thick and grey, so check that. 
JHeth is right: the first command `d="M16,22.2` moves the pen below the bottom of the viewbox. Making the viewbox 23 or 24 would help.

Comment: Just tweak your viewBox - part of the stroke is being drawn outside it. viewBox="-1 -1 24 24" works just great.